# Data Synchronization Between Elasticsearch and SQL

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

What is the most efficient solution for synchronizing data between Elasticsearch and SQL Server databases with a large number of tables i.e. two hundred, and how can this process be scheduled to run weekly?
I am trying make multi-pipelines to make a stable connection of SQL with Elasticsearch and sending large volume of data typically between five to six gigabytes.